# Select certain Date data from json Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to select only results from Date.today + 1.day from a parsed json series, but i have confused myself on how best to implement this.

json is formatted as:

```
{"status": "ok", "data": {"temperatures": [["2014-09-16 07:00", 14.4], ["2014-09-16 08:00", 17.6], ["2014-09-16 09:00", 20.5], ["2014-09-16 10:00", 23.0], ["2014-09-16 11:00", 24.8], ["2014-09-16 12:00", 26.4]]}}
```

Controller

```
dates = []
temps = []

@forecast['data']['temperatures'].each do |data|
 dates << data[0]
 temps << data[1]
end

dates.flatten.each do |d|
 dates << DateTime.parse(d).strftime("%d %b - %H:%M")
end

@results = dates.map {|f| [Date.today + 1.day(f), temps]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select data where date is greater than one day from now then:

```
@forecast['data']['temperatures'].select{|temp| temp[0].to_date > 1.day.from_now.to_date }
```

else if you want to select data where date is greater than or equal to one day from now:

```
@forecast['data']['temperatures'].select{|temp| temp[0].to_date >= 1.day.from_now.to_date }
```